# Swift Countdown Function

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am attempting to create a countdown timer for a game using SpriteKit, but whenever I try to run countDown(), my game freezes. I am pretty sure my logic is correct here. I do not know what is going on.

```
func countDown(){
    let countDownWait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.0)
        repeat {
            self.run(countDownWait){
                self.countDownTime -= 1
            }
        } while (self.countDownTime > 0)

        if self.countDownTime == 0{
            self.runGameOver()
        }
}
```

Comment: You are not showing all relevant lines of code.

Comment: You're blocking the main thread, so nothing else will happen while this loop is going

Comment: Alexander, what do you mean?

Comment: How and where are you calling `countDown` from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [countdown in swift and spritekit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24865420/countdown-in-swift-and-spritekit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do some checking in the update func for time passed or use a SKAction to track time similar to what you were doing in your code

```
let someLabel = SKLabelNode()

func countdown() {

    var offset: Double = 0

    for x in (0...10).reversed() {

        run(SKAction.wait(forDuration: offset)) {
            someLabel.text = "\(x)"

            if x == 0 {
                //do something when counter hits 0
                //self.runGameOver()
            }
            else {
                 //maybe play some sound tick file here
            }
        }
        offset += 1.0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved this problem for my Swift/SpriteKit 'Breakout' application. I wanted a countdown from 5 to 1 onthe main game screen but before the ball started to move. I Added these functions and then a call to countdown(5) at the end of `didMoveToView`: Notice the `ball.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(20, 20))` as the last step of `endCountdown`which starts the ball and effectively starts the game.

```
func countdown(count: Int) {
    countdownLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = .Center
    countdownLabel.verticalAlignmentMode = .Baseline
    countdownLabel.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height*(1/3))
    countdownLabel.fontColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
    countdownLabel.fontSize = size.height / 30
    countdownLabel.zPosition = 100
    countdownLabel.text = "Launching ball in \(count)..."

addChild(countdownLabel)

let counterDecrement = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0),
    SKAction.runBlock(countdownAction)])

runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.repeatAction(counterDecrement, count: 5),
    SKAction.runBlock(endCountdown)]))

}

func countdownAction() {
    count--
    countdownLabel.text = "Launching ball in \(count)..."
}

func endCountdown() {
    countdownLabel.removeFromParent()
    ball.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(20, 20))
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this solution to run countdown...

```
 var seconds = 7200
  var timer = Timer()



override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() 
         runTimer()
}

  func runTimer() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: (#selector(self.updateTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }
    @objc func updateTimer() {
        if seconds < 1 {
            timer.invalidate()
            //Send alert to indicate time's up.
        } else {
            seconds -= 1
            timerLabel.text = timeString(time: TimeInterval(seconds))
        }
    }

    func timeString(time:TimeInterval) -> String {
        let hours = Int(time) / 3600
        let minutes = Int(time) / 60 % 60
        let seconds = Int(time) % 60
        return String(format:"%02i:%02i:%02i", hours, minutes, seconds)
    }
```

Comment: Don’t use timers in SpriteKit.

Comment: then brother.. check your threads may be u r running your loop in main thread that will surly block your UI untill it finish...

Comment: SK games don't really talk about a main thread, or blocking the UI - it's just that SK has it's own game loop and places in the game loops where SKActions are evaluated and resolved, and timers are completely outside that game loop e,g if you pause your scene, everything will pause too unless it is running a timer.

Answer (score -2):

Have you considered using a timer? [Here is a good tutorial](http://www.ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/swift/swift-nstimer-tutorial-lets-create-a-counter-application/). It might take you 20 minutes to go through it or so, but it goes into detail about starting, stopping, pausing, and more for timers.

Comment: that is a UIKit tutorial not a Spritekit tutorial. Spritekit has it's own timing function built into the game loop and accessed through the update func

Comment: Don't use timers in Sprite Kit = use SKActions.